# Works locally but not over the internet

Tags: python, php, apache

I have a raspberry pi which has an Apache web server running on it. I have PHP files that I use to edit a .json file on the pi when those PHP files are visited in a web browser.

I've tested the code and when using the command line it all works perfectly I execute the PHP file and then it activates a python program that edits the .json file. However, when I try to access the PHP file over the internet, it loads but never actually edits the .json file.

Here is the code for the PHP file:

```
<?php 
    system ( "sudo python3 updater.py RLY1 1" );
 ?>
```

Heres the code for the python script:

```
import json
import sys

GPIOlabel = sys.argv[1]
state = sys.argv[2]

with open('data.json', 'r') as datafile:
    data = json.load(datafile)
    data[GPIOlabel] = state

with open('data.json', 'w') as datafile:
    json.dump(data, datafile)
```

I don't know how much help the code can be because like I said it works when I try it locally, maybe it's a problem with permissions? Any input as to why it doesn't work would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why are you running the command with `sudo`? The user running the Apache server (usually `www-data`) should not have permissions to run as superuser.

Comment: i added sudo after it didnt work, even with out the sudo it worked locally

Comment: Try adding the full paths to both the python executable and the python file: `/path/to/python3 /path/to/updater.py RLY1 1`.

Comment: Just tried adding the full paths and have the same issue, it works locally but wont work over the internet